# Drone local and local.properties

Tags: android, android-studio, docker, drone.io

I'm using drone for a ci/dev environment for building Android.  When running

`drone exec --local`

It gives an error:

`The SDK directory '/Users/zxxxxx/Library/Android/sdk' does not exist.`

This is the location of the sdk on my machine not on the docker image.  It looks as though Android Studio automatically creates a local.properties fild and sets sdk.dir.  This setting overrides environmental variables (i.e. ANDROID_HOME).

Does anybody know if

- A. We can tell Android Studio to not create local.properties and just use ANDROID_HOME ?
- B. Or can drone ignore that file.  I think the way drone/docker works is that it just mounts the project folder, so this probably won't work.
- C. Or some other way to solve this....